# How can I output WPAlchemy repeating fields meta values in my page template?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox, post-meta, wpalchemy

I have a custom post type, Downloads, which contains some custom metaboxes, including a repeating field. I'm able to output the values for all of them in my page template, but I'm not able to output the repeating fields' values in my page template.

In my downloads_meta.php, I have the following:

```
<div class="my_meta_control">
  <label>Includes:</label>
  <?php $metabox->the_field('cb_second_includes'); ?>
  <p><input type="checkbox" class="second-includes-check" name="<?php $metabox->the_name(); ?>" value="1"<?php $metabox->the_checkbox_state('1'); ?>/><span>Different bullet points for previous version?</span></p>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <?php while($metabox->have_fields_and_multi('docs')): ?>
    <?php $metabox->the_group_open(); ?>
      <?php $metabox->the_field('li-text'); ?>
      <?php $wpalchemy_media_access->setGroupName('li-n'. $mb->get_the_index())->setInsertButtonLabel('Insert'); ?>
      <div class="col includes">
        <?php echo $wpalchemy_media_access->getField(array('name' => $metabox->get_the_name(), 'value' => $metabox->get_the_value())); ?>
        <a href="#" class="dodelete button" style="float:right;">-</a>
      </div>
    <?php $metabox->the_group_close(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
  <p style="margin-bottom:0; padding-top:0;"><a href="#" class="docopy-docs button">+</a></p>
</div>
```

And in my page template I have:

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    // 'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post_type' => array('downloads'),
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'
  );

  $temp = $wp_query;
  global $wp_query;
  global $post;
  $wp_query= null;

  $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<?php
  if($wp_query->have_posts()) :
  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>

  <?php
    global $downloads_meta;
  ?>

  <ul>
    <?php while($downloads_meta->have_fields('docs')): ?>
      <li><?php echo $downloads_meta->get_the_value('li-text'); ?></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </ul>

<?php
  endwhile;
  endif;
?>
```

With the above code, I'm able to output values for my first custom post type, but the second two don't output anything for the repeating fields. I would appreciate any insights into what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: The WPAlchemy functions are just for backend admin metabox output, you just use the metadata as normal in the frontend, eg `$values = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $metabox_id . 'docs', true )` (or some such for the meta key, depends on the metabox id and the group field name and your WPAlchemy settings). Each entry should key to the field, eg `$values[$i]['li-text']` (again depending on WPAlchemy settings)...

Comment: Cool, thanks. How would I find the metabox ID? Would it be $downloads_meta?

Comment: It's just the id you gave as an argument to the WPAlchemy_MetaBox on construction, which personally I set as a define but that's just a nicety (it can also be accessed via `$downloads_meta->id` but that only makes sense really on the backend).

Comment: Still having trouble outputting the values correctly. Are you aware of any tutorials/examples of outputting values for repeating fields? WPAlchemy's documentation on this is light, and it focuses on an image upload.

Comment: Not in the position just at the moment but I'll get back to you!

Answer (score 1):

Per comments, here's a (very rough) example of accessing repeated fields in the frontend. Note using WPAlchemy extract mode, which gives each field its own meta entry, and makes accessing them a bit simpler.

Also using actions in "functions.php" to add metabox and to output content for test purposes - obviously you'd adapt the `'init'` code to your custom post type and put the `'the_content'` code in your page template.

Eg, in "functions.php":

```
define( 'METABOX_ID', 'my_meta_' );
add_action( 'init', function () {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        if ( ! class_exists( 'WPAlchemy_MetaBox' ) ) {
            require_once 'wpalchemy/MetaBox.php'; // Assuming subdirectory of current theme directory.
            require_once 'wpalchemy/MediaAccess.php'; // Assuming subdirectory of current theme directory.
        }
        global $wpalchemy_media_access;
        $wpalchemy_media_access = new WPAlchemy_MediaAccess();
        $download_meta = new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(
            array(
                'id' => METABOX_ID,
                'types' => array( 'post' ), // array( 'downloads' )
                'template' => get_stylesheet_directory() . '/download_meta.php',
                'priority' => 'default',
                'mode' => WPALCHEMY_MODE_EXTRACT,
                'prefix' => METABOX_ID,
            )
        );
    }
} );

// Just for testing - should be in the custom post type template.
add_action( 'the_content', function ( $content ) {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        // Access single-valued (non-array) meta.
        $ul_class = 'docs';
        if ( $cb_second_includes = get_post_meta( $post_id, METABOX_ID . 'cb_second_includes', true ) ) {
            $ul_class = 'docs_second_includes';
        }
        // Access array-valued meta.
        if ( $docs = get_post_meta( $post_id, METABOX_ID . 'docs', true ) ) {
            ob_start();
            ?>
            <ul class="<?php echo $ul_class; ?>">
            <?php foreach ( $docs as $doc ) : ?>
                <li><?php echo $doc['li-text']; ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php
            $content = $content . ob_get_clean();
        }
    }
    return $content;
} );
```

Here's the version of "download_meta.php" I used (note the metabox is addressed via `$mb`):

```
<?php global $wpalchemy_media_access; ?>
<div class="my_meta_control">
  <label>Includes:</label>
  <?php $mb->the_field('cb_second_includes'); ?>
  <p><input type="checkbox" class="second-includes-check" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="1"<?php $mb->the_checkbox_state('1'); ?>/><span>Different bullet points for previous version?</span></p>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <?php while($mb->have_fields_and_multi('docs')): ?>
    <?php $mb->the_group_open(); ?>
      <?php $mb->the_field('li-text'); ?>
      <?php $wpalchemy_media_access->setGroupName('li-n'. $mb->get_the_index())->setInsertButtonLabel('Insert'); ?>
      <div class="col includes">
        <?php echo $wpalchemy_media_access->getField(array('name' => $mb->get_the_name(), 'value' => $mb->get_the_value())); ?>
        <a href="#" class="dodelete button" style="float:right;">-</a>
      </div>
    <?php $mb->the_group_close(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
  <p style="margin-bottom:0; padding-top:0;"><a href="#" class="docopy-docs button">+</a></p>
</div>
```